# Web designers... for horizontal menus, is there an advantage of using multiple bullets?

Tags: html, css, header, menu

I'm thinking of just consolidating my menu to just an 
  `<li id="menu"><a href="News">News</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="blog">blog</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a

  href="other stuff">other stuff</a>`

This seems sooooo much less complicated than the typical web designer's choice of making each subsection, news, blog, otherstuff each different li ids. This way, you won't need to worry about consistency or anything.

So why do people use multiple li ids instead? I'm honestly curious. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because it's an actual list of items. Since HTML is markup, you want to make sure you use the right markup for the right content. This is the same reason that people don't use tables for presentation since tables are for tabular data and not presentation. Since your menu is a list you should use a list.

This is very apparent when you remove the style for your document. A well structured document with the proper markup will *still* make sense without any styles applied to it. And keep in mind that's how bots see it. And accessibility tools.

Comment: You also need the extra wrapping elements if you want any custom styling in regards to positioning with  padding, backgrounds, multiple images, etc.

Comment: I've heard that google crawlers can identify the look of a page (that's how google knows if you're cloaking anything) and so markup standards really don't matter all that much. I guess it really isn't that much work to use more bullets, but it makes sense to just make it one line, or so I thought.

Comment: @Ballscian1 yeah, that's true. With the elements in place you can completely change the look of the site without touching the markup

Comment: @user657847 yeah but even then a well structured document will be more easily understood by the bot

Comment: It more semantic to have each item be an actual list item. Rather than a single list item with multiple links. And +1 for accessibility.